# Programmatically invoked Storyboard-ViewController slow loading images

Tags: ios, image, swift, viewcontroller

I have designed a view with a couple of images. When I check "Is Initial View Controller" in Interface Builder, it displays fine, including the images. If I invoke it through code, the images are loading only after about 30 seconds. My images are defined in the Images.xcassets-file. It does not make a difference if I place this file in the root-project-directory or in a subfolder.

That's how I invoke the view :

```
// Tried different bundles here, e.g. NSBundle.mainBundle() or nil :
var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: parentView.nibBundle) 
var loginView : LoginViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController") as LoginViewController!

// Tried different PresentationStyle here, e.g. "FullScreen" :
loginView.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover 
parentView.presentViewController(loginView, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I have the same problem. I'm trying to support in app localization (not based entirely on the iOS, but to take some advantages of it). I using multiple storyboard (localized) but when initiating a new one (programatically), I get images missing. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Unfortunately I could not solve the issue yet - but I recognised that the images appear after about 30 seconds. So I have more of a "slow loading" issue than a "no images" issue. Did you try waiting in the view so we still have the same issue? I will edit my post to reflect the new behaviour.